# Why is my find -type d performing fstat on every file in a folder?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, find

I'm running `find . -type d` on a rather large directory tree. I am only interested in finding directories within this tree, but when I ran an strace against the process to make sure it was doing what I expected it to be doing, I noticed that there are a huge amount of operations being wasted running fstat against files within the tree.

```
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "file1", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0600, st_size=7690, ...}, AT_SYMLINK_NOFOLLOW) = 0
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "file2", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0600, st_size=7696, ...}, AT_SYMLINK_NOFOLLOW) = 0
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "file3", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0600, st_size=7687, ...}, AT_SYMLINK_NOFOLLOW) = 0
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "file4", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0600, st_size=10455, ...}, AT_SYMLINK_NOFOLLOW) = 0
```

Is find not aware that an inode is pointing to a directory until it performs an fstat? If that's the case, then this is going to take a long time. Some of these directories likely have millions of items within them, but I really only care about directories.

Ultimately I would like a report of the dirsize and path of each of the directories in my file tree. What's the fastest/most efficient way for me to do that?

Comment: Directories are infact files. 'find' uses fstat to find out if a file is - a file, a special file or a directory. From what I understand, even other core-utils tools use fstat to determine the basic information about a file. I don't think there is any more efficient way to read inode metadata other than stat syscall.

Comment: Hmmm....isn't the proper command "find . -type d -print"??

Comment: `-print` is an implicit outcome in modern `find`.  In fact, it's even worse: *everything* can be implied: `find` alone implies `find . -print`.

Comment: @mdpc correct the command as posted gives an error but also note that -print is implicit on modern find implementations.

Comment: The actual command I am running is `find */. -type d -exec ls -ld {} +`, so that I can see the size/location of the directory. Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: @MadHatter,@Iain - understand that -print is implicit just wanted to be very specific

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it looks like it really is the case that find is using [fstat](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html) to determine the type of the file. This is mildly surprising given that [dirent](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getdents.2.html) has contained the information since kernel 2.6.4.

Not all filesystems have support for the extended dirent behaviour so either this is true in your case or find doesn't use it. Without knowing your filesystem type we can't decide.

Comment: It's an NFS mount. Interestingly, I ran a perl script using `IO::Dirent` and it seems to be able to enumerate directories much faster, so perhaps `find` isn't the best tool for the job.

Comment: Interestingly there seems to be a feature of `find` called [d_type optimisation](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_node/find_html/d_005ftype-Optimisation.html) which can be enabled with `-o2` but it doesn't seem to have much effect in my case :(

Answer (score 1):

As I am sure you know, a directory is a special type of file in the UNIX paradigm. To determine whether something is a directory or another type of file, it must be interrogated, and fstat() is a good way to do this.

I believe later filesystems and fs-drivers keep a separate table of just the directories, but the find command dates back decades, and is probably either not adapted to newer filesystems or it maintains downward compatibility.

You could fake this by running a recurring job out of CRON (at a nice value >0 if you want to be easy on the IO utilization for other processes) that does a:

```
find ${DIRECTORY} -type d -print >${DIRECTORY}/.only_folders
```

Then when you need this, use the contents of the file that you prebuilt instead of traversing the directory again.

```
cat "${DIRECTORY}/.only_folders" |while read FOLDER ; do
  do_work.sh ${FOLDER} ;
done
```

instead of something like

```
find ${DIRECTORY} -type d |xargs do_work.sh
```